# Magento: category will continue showing up in main menu despite selected: Not include in menu

Tags: magento

I have been passed a developed magento shop and I wanted to remove from sight some categories from the main menu on the frontpage, yet, it will continue showing up despite having selected Included in Navigation Menu: No

That is, Catalog- Manage Categories- General Information

I also tried changing to: Is Active? No.

and then I click on save category, I refresh the frontpage and it keeps showing. I dont understand. I even checked with other browsers to make sure I wasn't seeing the cache.

I have then tried other thing. At the Directory tree of categories, I have dragged that category up to insert it inside another one. It should have then disappeared from the Main navigation menu and be included in the list of dropdown items.
Nothing of the sort happened. It continues showing up in the main menu despite the Directory tree having been changed.

I am flummoxed.

[image]

is there any secret behind what what was expected to be an straightforward matter?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: ok fair enough, no problem, close the question and I ll go there

Comment: Did you refresh the caches of Magento, and the Indexes ?

Comment: where is that exactly? I have seen videos where the author changed and removed categories without any further doing